# Understanding norm convergence of the truncated Hilbert transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

For $\epsilon > 0$ and $f \in L^p, p \geq 1$ then it is not difficult to show that the function
$$ H_\epsilon f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{|y| > \epsilon} \frac{f(x-y)}{y}dy $$
is well defined.  In fact, much like the Hilbert transform, $H_\epsilon$ is weak $(1,1)$ and strong $(p,p)$ for $1< p < \infty$.

What I'm working to understand is why if $f \in L^p, 1 \leq p < \infty$ then the sequence $\{H_\epsilon f\}$ converges to $Hf$ in $L^p$.  For now let's assume $p > 1$ (the $p=1$ case boils down to replacing norm convergence with convergence in measure in the following statements).  Letting $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions converging to $f$ in $L^p$ then I have
$$ \|Hf - H_\epsilon f\|_p \leq \|Hf - Hf_n\|_p + \|Hf_n - H_\epsilon f_n\|_p + \|H_\epsilon f_n - H_\epsilon f\|_p . $$

Given the strong $(p,p)$ inequalities of $H_\epsilon$ and $H$, then I am good with the first and third terms on the right-hand side of the inequality.  My struggle is with the middle term: I can't seem to understand why $H_\epsilon f_n$ would converge to $Hf_n$ in $L^p$.  I tried using the Minkowski inequality for integrals on said term, but to no avail.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is $Hf(x)$ defined as the pointwise limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} H_\epsilon f(x)$?

Comment: No, although it turns out being true almost everywhere.  Your statement is true for Schwartz functions.  We then extend the transform to $L^p, 1 \leq p < \infty$ using the weak $(1,1)$ and strong $(p,p)$ inequalities and sequences that converge in measure or norm.

Comment: Ok. Great. So here, in this question, I suppose that $f_n$ is Schwartz. Now, that same argument you just mentioned should give you that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\lVert H_\epsilon f_n-Hf_n\rVert_p = 0.$$

Comment: Hmm, I knew it had to have something to do with our sequence being Schwartz.  But I must be missing your point, in particular I don't see how the pointwise convergence for Schwartz functions implies their norm convergence.

Comment: I don't think that "pointwise convergence implies $L^p$ convergence". I think that the proof of pointwise convergence can be adapted to prove $L^p$ convergence. However, I have not tried, I cannot be sure.

Comment: Hello Oreomair, did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f$ a Schwartz function, we have that
$$
(H_\epsilon f-Hf)(x)=p.v. \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{f(x-y)}{y}dy=\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{f(x-y)-f(x)}{y}dy
$$
where we consider the integrand of the latter function to be continued to be a smooth function at $y=0$. We can then apply the mean value theorem to get pointwise the integrand is bounded by $\max_{y\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)}|f'(y)|$, so
$$
|(H_\epsilon f-Hf)(x)|\leq 2\epsilon \max_{y\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)}|f'(y)|.
$$
If we let $g(x)=\max_{y\in (x-1,x+1)}|f'(y)|$, then $g(x)$ will have rapid decay and for all $\epsilon<1$,
$$
|(H_\epsilon f-Hf)(x)|\leq 2 \epsilon \cdot g(x)\implies ||H_\epsilon f-Hf||_p\leq 2\epsilon ||g||_p.
$$
Taking $\epsilon$ to zero we are done.

Comment: Very nice!  I was reading a textbook that had a questionable approach to this, but this is very clear.